# Spark: count events based on two columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table with events which are grouped by a uid. All rows have the columns `uid`, `visit_num` and `event_num`.

`visit_num` is an arbitrary counter that occasionally increases. `event_num` is the counter of interactions within the visit.

I want to merge these two counters into a single interaction counter that keeps increasing by 1 for each event and continues to increase when then next visit has started.

As I only look at the relative distance between events, it's fine if I don't start the counter at 1.

`|uid   |visit_num|event_num|interaction_num|
|    1 |       1 |       1 |             1 |
|    1 |       1 |       2 |             2 |
|    1 |       2 |       1 |             3 |
|    1 |       2 |       2 |             4 |
|    2 |       1 |       1 |           500 |
|    2 |       2 |       1 |           501 |
|    2 |       2 |       2 |           502 |`

I can achieve this by repartitioning the data and using the `monotonically_increasing_id` like this:

```
df.repartition("uid")\
  .sort("visit_num", "event_num")\
  .withColumn("iid", fn.monotonically_increasing_id())
```

However the documentation states:

*The generated ID is guaranteed to be monotonically increasing and unique, but not consecutive. The current implementation puts the partition ID in the upper 31 bits, and the record number within each partition in the lower 33 bits. The assumption is that the data frame has less than 1 billion partitions, and each partition has less than 8 billion records.*

As the id seems to be monotonically increasing by partition this seems fine. However:

- I am close to reaching the 1 billion partition/uid threshold.
- I don't want to rely on the *current implementation* not changing.

Is there a way I can start each uid with 1 as the first interaction num?

**Edit**

After testing this some more, I notice that some of the users don't seem to have consecutive `iid` values using the approach described above.

**Edit 2: Windowing**

Unfortunately there are some (rare) cases where more than`one row has the same`visit_num`and`event_num`. I've tried using the windowing function as below, but due to this assigning the same rank to two identical columns, this is not really an option.

```
iid_window = Window.partitionBy("uid").orderBy("visit_num", "event_num")
df_sample_iid=df_sample.withColumn("iid", fn.rank().over(iid_window))
```

Comment: Have you considered using window aggregate functions like rank? That could work within partitions and then you'd have to apply `lag` or similar over the entire dataset. That could work (not sure how effective it'd be performance-wise).

Comment: I've tested Windowing with rank and it does the job as initially outlined in the question. Unfortunately, I discovered that it's causing some issue with duplicates rows, which I did not expect to see in the data.

Comment: What about `row_number`? Have you checked that?

Comment: I've settled on using the `rank` on the window with an additional column `date` which is due to data inconsistency. I've removed a (tiny) number of remaining inconsistent rows by using `drop_duplicates("visit_num", "event_num", "date")` So `window-rank` works fine, it just needed a bit more unexpected data cleansing.

Comment: Can you paste the solution as an answer and accept it? I'd appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is the Windowing function with rank, as suggested by Jacek Laskowski.

```
iid_window = Window.partitionBy("uid").orderBy("visit_num", "event_num")
df_sample_iid=df_sample.withColumn("iid", fn.rank().over(iid_window))
```

In my specific case some more data cleaning was required but generally, this should work.